# mongodb Push values into array variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I am writing a cleansing function which will delete all invalid docs from collection. For this I have an idea to push invalid _id values into array variable and delete with $in.

```
function(scan){
var err
for(var n=1;n<scan;n++){
var doc = db.zeroDimFacts.findOne({_id:n}) ,nKeys =0; 
for(k in doc)
    nKeys++
if(nKeys <5)
    err = n.toArray()
}
```

After I push all values to err Array, I have a script to delete matching docs. However, there is something missing with the code which throws me error at `n.toArray()` .
 
Can someone help me to correct the code?

Comment: what is the `criteria` here to find the invalid docs ?

Comment: as mentioned in the problem statement, criteria is to delete the invalid docs.

Comment: Not clear what is an invalid doc. If you explain it someone can help you do it in a criteria.

Comment: Hi Sherin, If you are asking how I assume a doc as invalid, it a simple check to count the number of keys, whereas it should be 5 in my case, if the keys are less then it fails in the criteria.

Comment: For this scope, a doc is considered as invalid if the keys are less than 5. If you see the code, I am trying to insert the _id values of docs which are having less than 5 keys.
In short, I don't want to immediately delete a doc if it is invalid, I want to push all the values into array and then delete in go at the end.

Comment: db.zeroDimFacts.findOne({_id:n}) without a callback function returns a promise. doc might be containing a non fulfilled promise. Please try to console doc.

Comment: Actually `findOne()` will return only one row, then how `nKeys` becomes greater or equal to `5`. Is it a right `criteria` ? And please note the point mentioned by @NidhinDavid. Try using `callbacks`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function(scan) {
    var doc;
    var nKeys;
    var err = [];

    for(var n = 1; n < scan; ++ n) {
        doc = db.zeroDimFacts.findOne({_id: n})
        nKeys = 0;

        for(k in doc) {
            ++ nKeys;
        }
        if(nKeys < 5) {
            err.push(n);
        }
    }
    return err;
};
```

Pay attention to findOne() call. When it returns null, n will get into the array which seems undesirable to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [findByIdAndRemove({criteria})](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndRemove) and depending on return value you can have the logic.

Comment: Hi, I am not working on mongoose, I am writing a function inside mongodb.

Comment: Will findOneAndDelete help : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndDelete/

Comment: I'm not sure on this, it may help in general scenario because it validates and delete the document in very successful iteration, it would take a longer time for a collection having millions of docs.
This is the reason why I have opted to first collect all the id of invalid docs and then input to delete them in one go.

Comment: Inserting in a bulk way is faster because before insertion all your docs are in memory and they are inserted to db->storage. But in delete case they are in db already - you can use db.collection.remove with some criteria. Collecting all ids and deleting them as you have explained might not be the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Also have a look at this - if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788841/fastest-way-to-delete-100m-documents-by-id

Comment: I am confused, I was told bulk delete would help in this scenario. However, since you have backed with some strong reference. It seems I should give it a try on this. Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: could you plz accept my answer to your question also post on results

Comment: I have to wait for sometime because I have a script ready to delete from Array. However, I would mark your suggestion as solution even if i get an answer to push values to array because it may help in other cases. So, I would wait for sometime and mark your suggestion.